# Extending package: undefined control sequence

Tags: packages, package-writing, undefined

I'm trying to add custom blocks in addition to the ones already defined by [scratch3](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/scratch3)

I made a top-level file **customblocks.sty** that currently contains

```
\ProvidesPackage{customblocks}
\RequirePackage{scratch3}
\definecolor{customcolor}{RGB}{100, 50, 200}
\newcommand*\ovalcustom{\scr_ovalbox0{customcolor}}
```

I just tried my best to copy and modify from the [scratch3.sty](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/scratch3) definitions, which look like:

```
\newcommand*\ovalsensing{%
    \scr_ifstar
        {\scr_ovalbox1{scrsensing}}
        {\scr_ovalbox0{scrsensing}}%
}
\def\scr_blocksensing{\scr_normalblock{scrsensing}}
\newcommand*\boolsensing{\scr_boolbox{scrsensing}}
```

I import my custom package in my preamble

```
\usepackage{scratch3}
\usepackage{customblocks}
```

Then I try to use it later on

```
\ovalcustom{attempting}
```

But I get *lots*  of errors, I think ultimately caused by

> Undefined control sequence.
> \ovalcustom ->\scr
> _ovalbox0{customcolor}
> l.10     \item \ovalcustom
> {attempting}
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message
> was never \def'ed

How can I actually add more blocks on top of the scratch3 package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the top of  `scratch3.sty` you'll see a block of code that (mainly) does

```
\catcode`\_11
```

and restores it at the end.

that makes `_` a letter so that `\scr_normalblock` is seen as a command with name `scr_normalblock`

You are using the code in a scope where `_` is a math subscript so
`\scr_normalblock` is `\scr _{n} ormalblock`  looking for an undefined command `\scr`

Comment: That makes sense and seems to be what I'm encountering while trying different things in my sty file. So should I copy/paste those relevant definitions from top of scratch3.sty into my file? How much of it is relevant, there are some `\long\def...` lines following which I cannot follow at all

Comment: @theonlygusti yes it is defing `\scr_restorecatcode` which you can call right at the end to put everything back to normal.